# How to go from a classical LSTM cell to a quantum LSTM cell where the neural network parts in the LSTM cell's gates are replaced by quantum circuits?

Tags: circuit-construction, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning, variational-quantum-algorithms

The input data I have is a tensor with shape (num_samples, num_timesteps, num_features). A single datapoint in my problem case is a feature vector of dim = 4 which conceptually corresponds to an single event in the [GDELT 1.0 Event Database](http://data.gdeltproject.org/events/index.html) (the dimensions have been reduced). 'num_timesteps' is the number of feature vectors (events) in a single sample (day), and a single sample is a sequence of 'num_timesteps' feature vectors. The target data is a tensor with shape (num_samples, num_timesteps, num_features) as well. [image]

The input x_t to the LSTM cell is shown in the figure. My goal would be to replace the neural network part in each gate of the LSTM cell by quantum circuits (QCs) so that the matrix multiplications would be done using QCs instead of the classical neural networks. Here is my model up to now.

```
x_sequences = [np.array(events) for events in padded_input_data[:-4]]
y_sequences = [np.array(events) for events in padded_input_data[1:-3]]

x = np.array(x_sequences)
y = np.array(y_sequences)

x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=tf.float32)

input_layer = Input(shape=(num_timesteps, num_features))
lstm_layer = LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, return_state=True,kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.01))

lstm_output, hidden_state, cell_state = lstm_layer(input_layer)

output = Dense(num_features, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.01))(lstm_output)
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output)

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])
model.summary()

batch_size =32# Number of days treated at once by the model during training 
epochs = 800

history = model.fit(x, y, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.3, shuffle=False)

test_sequences =  [np.array(events) for events in padded_input_data[-3:]]
test = np.array(test_sequences)
predicted_event = np.round(model.predict(test)).astype(int)
```

My understanding so far is that I would have to 1) access the hidden state and cell state of the LSTM cell (for each time step perhaps) to have in hand the 3 inputs (x_t, cell state & hidden state) for the LSTM cell and 2) designed a QC that would encode x_t, the cell state and the hidden state into quantum states (encoding layer) and then would do the matrix multiplication with the set of weights found in the matrices for all of the LSTM cell's gates (variational layer).

So far, I have found a way to encode x_t into the amplitude of a quantum state (amplitude encoding), but I'm still lacking the hidden state and the cell state (I'm not able to access them through my model...). I would also like to know if there is a convenient way to express the neural network part in the LSTM gates as VQCs ? I should also mention that the task I'm trying to perform is a regression one.

Overall, my questions are **A)** How to access the hidden state and cell state of the LSTM cell at each time step? and **B)** Is there a convenient way to express the neural network parts in the LSTM gates as VQCs for regression?

Sorry if it's unclear, I'm new to the field and I will precise furhter more my questions if needed. Thanks